# How can I create a new Buffer class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, not completely sure how to phrase this, but I'm gonna try my best.

I have been trying to use node's new `vm` module, and I wanted to enable Buffer support for the code running within the vm.

Here is the initial code I was using:

```
let vm = require('vm');
let someCode = '... some unsafe code ...';

let result = vm.runInNewContext(
    someCode,
    { Buffer: Buffer }
);
```

However, as I quickly discovered, this will return the node process's Buffer class, so if someone were to modify `Buffer.prototype` within the vm, this will also change the Buffer outside the vm.

Therefore, after looking at [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) I tried changing the sandbox object to:

```
{ Buffer: require('buffer').Buffer }
```

After some checking, I discovered to my dismay that this doesn't work as expected either, since require somehow returns the same object:

```
let b = require('buffer').Buffer;
console.log(b === Buffer); // This becomes true
```

Is it possible to create a new Buffer class using the vm, or will I have to further safeguard by using `child_process` in some fancy way?

Comment: You could pass a child class of `Buffer`, but I can't find any way to disable climbing up the prototype chain back into the original class - same appears to apply in fact for _any_ object you pass.

Comment: This actually seems like a giant security hole, if I pass inn `{}`, it seems that vm-code will be able to modify `Object.prototype`...

Edit: nevermind, that would be an instance, not the Object class itself...

Comment: looks that way, yes :(

Comment: it's still a hole, because node exposes the `__proto__` property of every instance that allows you to find its prototype.